# How/where is room template used

Tags: rocket.chat

I'm playing with the rocket.chat ui, and taking the room template out of context breaks it. It's a global template therefore nothing imports it. I'm trying to use it exclusively within D.M. channels if its relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be the fact that the room must be opened by app/lib/lib/direct.js although I can't believe that can affect the layout quite so much that like nothing really works.